# PyMesh Gradient Finite Element Matrix Meaning

Tags: python, graphics, scipy, geometry, computer-vision

I have a large mesh of `n` vertices and `m` faces.

I have run it through [PyMesh](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh) and wanted to find the gradient at each vertex in the mesh. I thought I would do this using [PyMesh's Finite Element Matrix Assembler](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_matrix_assembly.html?highlight=element) and passing through the gradient option.

I don't actually know if this even the correct way to get the gradients at each vertex.

But either way, my matrix which comes out at the end has shape `(m*3, n)` which has thrown me a bit, what do the coords refer too? `n` i presume refers to which vertex we are referencing... and I thought the m*3 might somehow refer to the xyz rotations for gradient... but really I don't know, can't find docs on it, the source is tricky to read and therefore I'm here.

Here is an example of the kind of numbers I'm looking at:

```
(435911, 80432)       -9.804509660667616
(435912, 80432)       936.4309752103766
(435913, 80432)       -98.04854297538037
(435914, 80432)       -925.9446430206171
(435915, 80432)       1241.5453781754534
(435916, 80432)       -620.7037763452347
(435917, 80432)       -620.7963685632036
(432924, 80433)       602.9591586766036
(432925, 80433)       301.5283336887832
(432926, 80433)       301.4729714158947
(432927, 80433)       454.6886045833549
(432928, 80433)       -47.62093162068515
(432929, 80433)       449.7195490288566
(432930, 80433)       9.807752883147764
(432931, 80433)       -185.18202015683497
(432932, 80433)       -9.804487985383732
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can't find a `pymesh` tag, there probably aren't many (if any) posters on SO who are familiar with the package.  Do you expect us to find something in its docs that you couldn't?

Comment: @hpaulj I was more hoping to find people who might know more about the function which it is trying to produce, which shouldn't be specific to the library.

Comment: What is the definition of "gradient" here? It is usually derivatives of a scalar field (i.e. how the temperature varies around a point in 3D space along each basis direction, for instance), but here it seems more like the normal vector of a surface? or a scalar? (what are the dimensions of the geometry 2D, 3D?)

Comment: I don't know the package, but the gradient matrix usually does the following: You can encode any (scalar) field defined at the vertices by a single `n`-d vector. If you multiply the matrix by this vector, you get a `3m`-d vector. Three components of this vector describe the gradient of the scalar function within the corresponding face (either interleaved or stacked).